# Kong as Gateway, serving UI with React

Tags: reactjs, nginx, reverse-proxy, kong

We try to serve an UI via [Kong Gateway](https://konghq.com/kong/).

Example:

```
services:
- name: portal-homepage
  url: http://host.docker.internal:8080
  routes:
  - name: portal-homepage
    paths:
      - /portal-homepage
    methods:
      - GET
      - OPTIONS
```

This works fine, but the React UI is trying to fetch statics like js, images, favicon from "localhost:8000/js/" instead of "localhost:8000/portal-homepage/js/".

If I change the base path for React, to "/portal-homepage" everything runs like expected, but we do not want to modify the existing application.

Is there any chance to tell "Kong" to handle this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with kong. The issue is that the UI will generated urls and kong is not the right place to modify these urls. So best way is to use the baseurl during the build itself

Comment: https://konghq.com/blog/url-rewriting-in-kong

I am not sure but this link can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a fix for this by using a build environment variable in react app
for example in react app .env file:

```
PUBLIC_URL=http://[kong]/portal-homepage
```

then within react iteself(index.html) :

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo.ico" />
```

and by this ur react app will send build and replace correctly.